# Undefined method `collection_check_boxes' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My collection select is just working fine

```
<%= f.collection_select :semester_id, Semester.all, :id, :name %>
```

But I also need to use check box and I used collection check box and I am getting this error  **Undefined method `collection_check_boxes'**

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :subject_ids, Subject.all, :id, :name %>
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between subject and your the model to save?

Comment: no relationship. I just need to save the subject id in my model

Comment: Are you using form builder, formtastic or simple form?

Comment: Which version of Rails do you use?

Comment: Have you tried without the `f.`?

Answer (score 0):

I think collection_check_boxex is not a method of form_builder, instead use:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:your_instance_model_to_save, Subject.all, :id, :name) %>
```

I'm not sure, i hope it help you.

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes

Comment: A FormBuilder object is associated with a particular model object and allows you to generate fields associated with the model object. The FormBuilder object is yielded when using form_for or fields_for.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html

Comment: Please try to use your collection_check_boxes separately of your form object f.